# Why aren't canonical redirects working for me in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, web

I use Hexo as a static site generator for my website [codefoster.com](http://codefoster.com), and I use the alias plugin to generate redirects so I can create shortlinks like `codefoster.com/slug`.

The alias generates the following...

`html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Redirecting...</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://1drv.ms/p/s!AvStLR7eqJbDyaZpnDDMJvbGtLrI5w">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://1drv.ms/p/s!AvStLR7eqJbDyaZpnDDMJvbGtLrI5w">
  </head>
</html>`

An example is a recent presentation I gave on VS Code. I added the alias `/deck/codeyourcode` to my `_config.yml` and the URL [codefoster.com/deck/codeyourcode](http://codefoster.com/deck/codeyourcode) now correctly generates the redirect.

My problem is that the redirect works in Edge, but in Chrome it triggers a file download. How do I tell Chrome to navigate to the redirect URL?

--- added 3/26/2018 ---

I haven't gotten this working yet, but I've narrowed it down. It's not *every* link on my site that's being served as an `application/octet-stream`. It's only the ones that I redirect (via the [alias extension](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-generator-alias/blob/master/lib/generator.js) for my Hexo static site generator) to a one drive share. Furthermore, it's only when I'm redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS.

So I guess my ultimate question now is how to do an

So http://codefoster.com/deck/codeyourcode redirects to an HTTPS URL and fails, whereas http://codefoster.com/codechat/071 redirects to an HTTP URL and it works. If you use `curl` with a `-v` on those, you'll see that the HTTP results in a `text/html` whereas the HTTPS results in an `application/octet-stream`.

This is likely by design, but how do I accomplish what I'm trying to do beyond getting codefoster.com working over HTTPS?

--- more edits ---

I am able to take the `s` off of the alias and it still fails, so it's not because it's going to an HTTPS protocol specifically, but it's actually looking at the redirect URL and *determining* for some unknown reason that it should be an `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: What web server are you using? It's not responding with a `Content-Type` header; I'm surprised it works in Edge.

Comment: @ZebMcCorkle For me it's actually responding with an application/octet-stream content type. Changing that to text/html should probably do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I think we're on the right track here. I'm serving static files using Express and it's serving them as application/octet-stream. I just have to figure out how to change that.

Comment: @JeremyFoster Just curious, have you managed to fix this? If so perhaps you can answer your own question to help others.

Comment: I haven't gotten this working yet. I added some more information to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out!

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')

express()
  .use(express.static(__dirname, {
    setHeaders: (res, requestPath) => {
      let noExtension = !Boolean(path.extname(requestPath));
      if(noExtension) res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    }
  }))

  .listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Every time a request is handled, it looks at the extension name of the requested path and if there is *not* an extension, then it sets the `Content-Type` header to `text/html`. Works a charm!